# Visual Studio 2013 returning 404 when adding a NuGet package source

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am trying to add an internal package source for NuGet to Visual Studio 2013 but it returns a 404 error. However, when I attempt to access the same URL in IE or Chrome, it prompts me for my name/password and successfully displays the XML. VS never prompts me for credentials in the package browser and when I cancel it, it says there's a 404. When I attempt it from the command line, it immediately returns a 404. I've also tried to manually add the package credentials to the global nuget.config but that's not helping either. Why isn't VS able to get to the URL like the browser is?

Comment: What is your path of nuget server ? Is your own nuget server? If yes, please check the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407799/nuget-installing-individual-packages-reporting-the-remote-server-returned-an

Comment: No it is not my own and it works for other people on my team, just not on my laptop.